# How can I make this tiktok downloader, transcriber, and data enterer run continuous and make a new transcription?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, transcription, tiktok

I am not a Python expert, nor probably even a Python amateur, but I've been learning and editing a script for a project around getting TikTok data. So I'm sure my code is probably a bit of a mess since I'm learning as I go.

Okay, I have a script that can download a TikTok, or set of TikTok's, transcribe the speech, and then output the data I'm looking for and the transcription into a .CSV, but I'm at an impasse when it comes to making it run continuously and update the transcript per video.

What I want is for the program to download the TikToks one at a time and transcribe them, then use the provided dictionary from the TikTok API to write the data from the video to a .CSV along with an additional column that uses the text from the transcription. Right now it does those things, but I have no clue how to write the new transcript from the subsequent videos as an updating column like the data currently is. I would also like to learn how to make the program loop until stopped, instead of having a predefined count of videos.

Let me know if that all makes sense or if you have ideas for making this better.

````
verifyFp="tiktok_fp"

api = TikTokApi.get_instance(custom_verifyFp=verifyFp, custom_device_id=did, use_test_endpoints=True)

hashtag='hashtag'

videofun=api.by_hashtag(hashtag=hashtag, count=2)

temp_count=0

transcript_list=[]


############################################################################################################

for i in range(len(videofun)):

        data = api.get_video_by_tiktok(videofun[i])# bytes of the video
        with open("downloads/{}.mp4".format(str("video")), 'wb') as output:
            output.write(data) # saves data to the mp4 file
            transcribed_audio_file_name = "transcribed_speech.wav"
            video_file_name = r"downloads\video.mp4"

            audioclip = AudioFileClip(video_file_name)
            audioclip.write_audiofile(transcribed_audio_file_name)

            apikey = 'IBM watson api key'
            url = 'IBM url'

            authenticator = IAMAuthenticator(apikey)
            stt = SpeechToTextV1(authenticator=authenticator)
            stt.set_service_url(url)

            with open('transcribed_speech.wav', 'rb') as f:
                res = stt.recognize(audio=f, content_type='audio/wav', model='en-AU_NarrowbandModel').get_result()

            res

            len(res['results'])
            text = [result['alternatives'][0]['transcript'].rstrip() + '.\n' for result in res['results']]

            text = [para[0].title() + para[1:] for para in text]
            transcript = ''.join(text)

            with open(r'\transcription.txt', 'w') as out:
                out.writelines(transcript)

        def simple_dict(tiktok_dict):

            to_return = {}
            to_return['user_name'] = tiktok_dict['author']['uniqueId']
            to_return['user_id'] = tiktok_dict['author']['id']
            to_return['video_id'] = tiktok_dict['id']
            to_return['video_desc'] = tiktok_dict['desc']
            to_return['video_time'] = tiktok_dict['createTime']
            to_return['video_length'] = tiktok_dict['video']['duration']
            to_return['video_link'] = 'https://www.tiktok.com/@{}/video/{}?lang=en'.format(to_return['user_name'], to_return['video_id'])
            to_return['n_likes'] = tiktok_dict['stats']['diggCount']
            to_return['n_shares'] = tiktok_dict['stats']['shareCount']
            to_return['n_comments'] = tiktok_dict['stats']['commentCount']
            to_return['n_plays'] = tiktok_dict['stats']['playCount']



            return to_return


tiktoks = [simple_dict(v) for v in (videofun)]
tiktoks_df = DataFrame.from_dict(tiktoks)
tiktoks_df.to_csv('tiktoks.csv'.format(hashtag),index=False)
print(transcript_list)```
````

Comment: if you want to loop forever then put in loop `while True:`

Comment: @furas - The problem I'm having with while True is that I'm not sure how to set the count in other places to make it actually output the final result before moving back to the next Tiktok, which might or might not actually be possible with the API.